# mongodb - A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field. - on creating view

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a simple view from a aggregate query:

```
db.stad.aggregate([
  {$unwind: {path: "$uitslag" }},
  {$group: {_id: "$uitslag.partij", aantal_stemmen: "$uitslag.stemmen" }}
])
```

But when I select "create a view" in MongoDB compass and click create I get the following error:

```
A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.
```

This how one of the "stad" documents look like:

```
_id:60c3c759c2678f2d40edc037
name:"Amsterdam"
aantal_inwoners:853312
aantal_kiesgerechtigd:625000
uitslag:Array
0:Object
partij:"GroenLinks"
stemmen:80000
1:Object
partij:"D66"
stemmen:70000
2:Object
partij:"PvdA"
stemmen:60000
3:Object
partij:"FvD"
stemmen:30000
4:Object
partij:"VVD"
stemmen:25000
5:Object
partij:"Denk"
stemmen:5000
```

I am fairly new to MongoDB but could not find a solution in the documentation

Comment: @turivishal unfortunately that did not work, I still get the same error..

Comment: can you show createView command that you have executed.